# sqlite exception while creating db

Tags: android, sqliteopenhelper

Im trying to create table using the following sqlite query.

```
private static final String CREATE_EMPLOYEE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_EMPLOYEE + "("
            + KEY_DOMAIN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
            + KEY_FROM + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_TO + " TEXT" + ")";

private static final String CREATE_GROUPS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_GROUPS + "("
        + KEY_USERID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
        + KEY_NAME + " TEXT,"
        + KEY_SESSION_TOKEN + " TEXT,"
        + KEY_GROUP_ID + " TEXT,"
        + KEY_GROUP_NAME + " TEXT" + ")";`
```

Im using the following code to add elements to db,

```
db.addEmployees(new Employee(id,from,to));
db.addGroup(new Group(Integer.valueOf(userId),name,session,groupId,groupName));
```

Both of those queries throws following error message

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "group": syntax error
>   (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE group(userId INTEGER PRIMARY
>   KEY,name TEXT,sessionToken TEXT,groupId TEXT,groupName TEXT)

Comment: group is reserved keyword in `sql` so change table name `group` to something like `group_`

Comment: Another option is escape group with `

Comment: Also `FROM` and `TO` are reserved SQL keywords

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rename variable

`String TABLE_GROUPS = "group"`

to something like

`String TABLE_GROUPS = "groups"`

> `group` is reserved keyword in `sql`.

[Check here the list of reserved keywords in `SQLite`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html)

Comment: that works but throws another exception `android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "to": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO employee(to,from,domainId) VALUES (?,?,?)`

Comment: @stanly you insist using reserved keywords: `FROM` and `TO` are reserved SQL words.

Comment: `to` is again reserved word in sqlite.so change the column name 'to' to 'to_' or something like that..

Answer (score 1):

Your table name can't be Group, **Group** is a keyword in Sqlite and **To** is also keyword

see the other keyword in Sqlite listed here.. https://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html